# Shir Hashirim passage after L'chah Dodi

Tags: shabbat, leil-shabbat, shir-hashirim, erev-shabbat

In [this](http://www.piyut.org.il/tradition/80.html?section=morePerformances&currPerformance=90&playing=0) Moroccan recording of L'chah Dodi, sung by Sami Elmaghribi, there is an interesting passage directly following it, containing four verses from Shir Hashirim:

Yishakeni min'shikot pihu, ki tovim dodeicha miyayin. (1:2)

Uri tzafon uvoi teiman, hafichi gani yizlu v'samav; yavo dodi l'gano, v'yochal pri m'gadav. (4:16)

Kol dodi, hineh zeh ba; m'daleg, al heharim -- m'kapetz, al hag'vaot. (2:8)

Bati l'gani, achoti chalah -- ariti mori im b'sami, achalti ya'ri im divshi shatiti yeini im chalavi; ichlu reim, sh'tu v'shichru dodim. (5:1)

Why are those verses sung there?  Is this a particular tradition regarding Kabbalat Shabbat in some communities?  Is it just a separate text that happened to be in the same recording?  Is there some online siddur that contains this passage?

Answer (score 3):

These Pesukim start with the letters יעקב. This is generally said by Sephardic people (not sure about Ashkenazim/Temanim) who didn't have time to say Shir HaShirim, but Moroccans seem to always say it. The Avodat hashem Sephardic Siddur contains this passage and an explanation. The Pe'er Yisrael Moroccan Siddur also has this passage. AFAIK, no online siddur has this passage.

Comment: teimonim say it today out of ignorance not out of their original tradition. same thing goes for lacho dodi itself.

Comment: Do you know why they chose those pesukim